# jQuery animate() - multiple selectors and variables, a unique animate() call

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

I am resizing several divs in a loop with animate() in jQuery. At the same time I am moving (left property, no resizing at all) the div where they are contained.

Problem is, despite they have same duration the resize animate calls finish before the move call. They are out of sync. Is there any way of creating a list of selectors and its properties and then run a unique animate() call?

Or, is there any alternative to make multiple animations happen at the same time?

I've seen there's a property called step that happens every time animate loop happens but, again, each animate() call has it's own step call.

Thanks in advance :)

Here's a kind of pseudocode example as required:

```
for(...){
    $(target_x).stop().animate({property_a:random_value, property_b:random_value}, {duration:300});
    }
$(container).stop().animate({property_z:random_value}, {duration:300});
```

Comment: Can you show your code. How do you resize and move the elements? I am a bit confused because animate is able to change multiple properties at once out of box. Maybe you have to reread the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Could you post the code so we can see if there are any issues with it? If they have the same duration I can't see why they would be noticeably out of sync.

Comment: I just posted some pseudocode so that you get the idea. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try wrapping all those functions each one in a `setTimeout(function() { $(target).animate(...) }, 0)` to emulate a parallel execution.

Comment: @stagas but the animate to the container is outside the loop. That's why I was asking for something different to group them all and make sure they all happen at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [asking something different but somehow related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060652/jquery-multiple-selectors-multiple-values-in-one-call) I found there was no solution to it.

The best workaround is using the step callback function as suggested [here](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/). Thanks to [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) for the link.

Answer (score 0):

@ozke: So far it is tuff to suggest you some idea with out detail code. Still such case of multiple animation synchronization working smoothly all together, it would be better if you adjust the animation duration practically(trial and testing),i.e slower the outer and faster the inner animations...

Comment: But with trial/testing it will perform different depending on the browser. Isn't it?

Comment: nope cause u r suffering timing problem and time r browser independent

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the stop() to
    .delay(400)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the animation queue and dequeue. Chain accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't queue create a sequence? Because I want the oposite. Add lots of animations and play them all at once.