# jQuery - Multiple selectors & multiple values in ONE call

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I was wondering whether there's a way of using multiple selectors in jQuery and setting different values for them IN ONE CALL.

E.g.:

```
$(selector1, selector2, selector3, ...).css({left:[532, 112, 453, ...]});
```

Thanks in advance

**Edited:** Just to be clear you can only call **.css** once. Is it possible?

**Edited again to clarify:** I'm asking because if, for instance, I call animate()... I'd like to keep a unique synchronized call/loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no you can't do that, the selector and the methods you call aren't connected like that.  The selector gets you a set of elements, when that happens the `.css()` (or any other) function doesn't know what position the element you're in was in the selector.

If you think about it,  it could be **all** positions, then what should it do?

For example:

```
$("#div, .class1, .class2").css({left:[532, 112, 453]});
```

What should this do on this HTML:

```
<div id="div" class="class1 class2"></div>
<div id="div2" class="class2 class1"></div>
```

You see how it gets confusing real fast, so no, nothing like this is supported.

To be fair, [`.css()` *does* take a functio](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)n, like this:

```
$("#div, .class1, .class2").css('left', function(i, val) {
  //return new left property here
});
```

But these elements are in the order they occur in the **document**, not related to the selector at all.

Comment: I'm asking because if, for instance, I call animate()... I'd like to keep a unique synchronized call/loop.

Comment: @ozke - `.animate()` is also called on *each* element, they're all animated independently,  though they may have *started* at the same time...given that, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I guess .animate uses a setInterval function. Well, I was wondering whether there's a way of using that setInterval once for all the selectors/properties. Other ways, it's impossible to keep perfect sync of the animations.

Comment: @ozke - Ah, now we get to the issue :)   You *can* share that interval, `.animate()` one for example, and use the [`step` function option](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the others, it fires for each frame/interval of the animation.  Here's an example: http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/

Comment: That's one option I thought about but making lots of calculations inside "step" feels like a too complex solution for such a simple thing, isn't it? (imagine the calculations for multiple properties and multiple selectors...). 

That's why I was asking myself of a simpler way. I guess there's no alternative :(

Comment: @ozke - Try and calculate your totals outside, like `.animate()` does, then each step is just total/frameCount, you can even pre-calculate that :)

Comment: I guess that's what I'll do. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is to use `.each()` for example:

```
$(selector1, selector2, selector3).each(function(idx, element){

  switch(idx)
{
   case : 0
      $(element).css('left', '345');
      break;
   case: 1
      $(element).css('left', '456');
      break;
}
});
```

EDIT:

the best I can come up with is this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {


    $("div#hello, div#hello1").css('background-color', function(idx, element){

        switch(idx)
        {
            case 0:
                return 'red'

            case 1:
                return 'green'
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hello">
    <span>test</span>
</div>

<div id="hello1">
    <span>test2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But you're calling .css serveral times, not one.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change one css value:

```
var values = [532, 112, 453, ...];
$(selector1, selector2, selector3, ...).css('left', function (i, current) {
    return values[i];
});
```

Why do you want to do it like that anyway?

jQuery will always loop through all values internally.. it's not magic (and you need to guarantee the index position for each selector will always be the same).

Comment: As I noted in my answer...the order is not what you think here, it's `document`, not `selector` based.  Given that, I'm not sure how it'd be useful at all...

Answer (score 0):

No - not possible (after you have clarified that .css() is allowed to be called exactly once)

Please Note:
1. selector1, selector2, selector3 can match el1, el4, el5, el6
2. Just because something is done behind one function call doesn't mean it is efficient
3. Doing what you are asking doesn't make code easier to read - this makes sense for left but how about some other properties